# Put all lines in output into one line

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following while loop:

```
while workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l] != 'h1':
        abstract_tag = workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l]
        abstract = abstract_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
        l += 1
        print(abstract)
```

How do I join the `<p>` tags that are printed all into one line.

For example at the moment there might be something like this:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

And I need it like this:

```
<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: `print(abstract, end = '')`

Comment: The alternative would be to put them in a list. `abstracts = []` outside the loop, `abstracts.append(abstract)` instead of `print(abstract)` and lastly outside the loop (after) `print(''.join(abstracts))`

Comment: @AntonvBR I was literally typing that.

Comment: @tgikal hehe.your solution works too and is great... but it will make the next print statement be on the same row.. so maybe one print statement extra is needed in the end. Depends on the why are we printing in the first place though.

Comment: @AntonvBR exactly the real method used here needs to be decided on what the end use is, if it is just to display than print would fine, if this information will be used somewhere else, than a list is much more useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: This seems to break the loop for some reason, but the error i get is to do with my own code so not sure why it is breaking the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (with the help of Keyur Potdar):

Create an empty string:

```
x = ''
```

Then concatenate each element in the loop:

```
x += abstract.decode('utf-8')
```

Output of `x`:

```
<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p>
```

Comment: The OP gets the text in a loop, and hence can't store it in the variables like you've shown. If you want to use this approach, you can do `x += abstract` inside the loop.

Comment: I had this error? TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: See update on answer. Try again. The reason you are getting this error is because you are encoding it before concatenating (i have no idea why). So you have to decode it.

Comment: It almost works, but it then infinitely prints the abstract and won't break the while loop? But it does put it all into one line

Comment: This is because `workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l] != 'h1'` seems to be always true. We don't know the rest of your code. So we can't help you with that on this post.

Comment: did it just had to put break in at the end, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
print(abstract)
```

with

```
print(abstract, end='')
```

if this is Python 3.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the correct way, though it could also have the usage for python2.